# How to see all Hadoop counter when running pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I run my pig via the command line, and I want to see all Hadoop counters after the run is finish.
I have written UDF that write to Hadoop counter base on this [blog](http://www.philippeadjiman.com/blog/2010/01/07/hadoop-tutorial-series-issue-3-counters-in-action/), but I want to test it - when the pig start I can see logs from the  the constructor, but later I see no log

Currently all I see is simple static - see below

```
Counters:
Total records written : 3487
Total bytes written : 38078
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 101
Total records proactively spilled: 12464701
```

Answer (score 0):

Pig job is actually a MapReduce job so you could see the status of the job and its complete list of counters from JobTracker page (if using MR1) or Application Master page (if using YARN).

Answer (score 0):

A single pig script may create multiple jobs depending on the complexity. You can query *all* the counters for each job from the command line by running

```
mapred job -status <job-id>
```

If you know the actual counter you are interested you can retrieve individual counters with

```
mapred job -counter <job-id> <group-name> <counter-name>
```

Of course, you need to know the job-id(s) - those should be available in the original pig output following the line 'Job DAG:'